# OutOfMemoryError when reading more than one asset

Tags: java, android, file-io, out-of-memory, android-assets

I have a function that reads asset files and stores their contents in arrays. Here's a code.

```
private List<String> infinitivesDB;
private List<String> formsDB;

private void getDB(String lang, String type)
    {
        while(true)
        {
        try {
            String infinitivesDB = getStringFromAssetFile(this, "inf.txt");
            this.infinitivesDB = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(infinitivesDB.split("\n")));
            break; //would be needed if it was reachable
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
        while(true)
        {
        try {
            String formsDB = getStringFromAssetFile(this, "forms.txt");//EXCEPTION HERE?        
            this.formsDB = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(formsDB.split("\n")));
            break; //would be needed if it was reachable
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    }
```

File "inf.txt" is 58kb. File "forms.txt" is 3.5 Mb.

Whenever I try to run this code, it raises an OutOfMemoryError. Here's the log

```
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): Process: com.highstaker.formdictionary, PID: 2017
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.expandBuffer(Scanner.java:2067)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.readMore(Scanner.java:2031)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.findDelimiterAfter(Scanner.java:2009)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.setTokenRegion(Scanner.java:1923)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:541)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:519)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.highstaker.formdictionary.MainActivity.convertStreamToString(MainActivity.java:411)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.highstaker.formdictionary.MainActivity.getStringFromAssetFile(MainActivity.java:404)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.highstaker.formdictionary.MainActivity.getDB(MainActivity.java:389)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.highstaker.formdictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
07-27 02:40:13.399: E/AndroidRuntime(2017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 02:40:15.179: I/Process(2017): Sending signal. PID: 2017 SIG: 9
```

But, if I try to read only one file (by commenting out one of while loops and its contents), no matter which file I pick - it works fine. If I try to read the "inf.txt" (smaller) in both loops and store in these different arrays, it works fine as well.

Moreover, if I simply switch the "whiles" and therefore read the larger file before the smaller one, it also works!

I'd like to know why this is happening. Also, how can I read two asset files if they were both big? I tried to read "forms.txt"(larger) in both loops and it raised the same error (I expected that, really).

Comment: I doubt the error came from within this code. Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: The problem is more in the method `getStringFromAssetFile` could you post the code of it.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is Being Caused Because you are trying to load plenty of data in string from a 3.5 mb file. the Quick Solutions for this Purpose are

You can use android:largeHeap="true" to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

The only way to have as large a limit as possible is to do memory intensive tasks via the NDK, as the NDK does not impose memory limits like the SDK.

Alternatively, you could only load the part of the model that is currently in view, and load the rest as you need it, while removing the unused parts from memory. However, this may not be possible, depending on your app.

Applications running on API Level 11+ can have android:largeHeap="true" on the  element in the manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size, and getLargeMemoryClass() on ActivityManager will tell you how big that heap is. However:

This only works on API Level 11+ (i.e., Honeycomb and beyond)

There is no guarantee how large the large heap will be

The user will perceive your large-heap request, because it will force their other apps out of RAM terminate other apps' processes to free up system RAM for use by your large heap

Because of #3, and the fact that I expect that android:largeHeap will be abused, support for this may be abandoned in the future, or the user may be warned about this at install time (e.g., you will need to request a special permission for it)

Presently, this feature is lightly documented

Answer (score 0):

I can see several bad design decisions here. Above all: if you need a file as list of strings, why don't you simply read it as that?

The stream is read using a Scanner, which in itself isn't required. Other io classes let you read lines without this complication.

The looong String is the split into a big array and that will finally produce the list. Thus, you have the file in memory at least in triplicate.

A LinedList grows efficiently, but you don't need that here. An ArrayList is more space-conserving.

getStringFromAssetFile must be redesigned.